# ¿Como solucionar la linea blanca en React?

Tags: css, reactjs

Mi pequeño problema es ue quiero hacer un navbar, pero no se porque aparece una linea banca justo arriba de mi navbar, se ve asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden notar hay una barra blanca que no se como quitarla, bien mi codigo del estilo en app es:

```
.navbar{
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}

.margin-browser{
  margin: 0%;
}

.nav-dark{
  color: white;
  background-color: #171717;
}
```

Y para mi index.js, su estilo es:

```
body {
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', 'Roboto', 'Oxygen',
    'Ubuntu', 'Cantarell', 'Fira Sans', 'Droid Sans', 'Helvetica Neue',
    sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

html{
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0%;
}

code {
  font-family: source-code-pro, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, 'Courier New',
    monospace;
}
```

Intente usar margin y padding pero no tiene ningun efecto, otra cosa que tambien vi, es que sucede cuando uso texto, ya sea parrafo o un titulo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Yo trataria de solucionarlo poniendo un position fixed o sticky de la siguiente forma:

```
 html,body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
 }

 .margin-browser{
  margin: 0;
 }

 .navbar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 50px;
 }
```

Aunque bueno eso de hacer resets de css asi no es muy bueno que digamos cuando existe normalize.css

Answer (score 0):

Hola ese espacio aparece porque la etiqueta p de parrafo tiene un margin por defecto de 16px entonces la solucion es poner un margin 0 en la etiqueta p.